# Tomcat not recovering from excess trafic

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

When my tomcat (6.0.20) maxThreads limit is reached, i get the expected error:

> Maximum number of threads (XXX) created for connector with address null and port 80

And then request starts hanging on queue and eventually timing out. so far, so good.
The problem is that when the load goes down, the server does not recover and is forever paralysed, instead of coming back to life.

Any hints?

Comment: I have the same issue even when the NIO connector is being used. After the max connection + queue capacity gets exhausted, all requests are getting rejected, which is expected. But after some time when the requests which are currently being processed get served, I expected other pending requests to get served successfully. This doesn't happen. All the requests keep getting rejected for quite a long time. Using tomcat 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider switching to [NIO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html#Nio_Implementation), then you don't need to worry about the technical requirement of 1 thread per connection. Without NIO, the limit is about 5K threads (5K HTTP connections), then it blows like that. With NIO, Java will be able to manage multiple resources by a single thread, so the limit is much higher. The border is practically the available heap memory, with about 2GB you can go up to 20K connections.

Configuring Tomcat to use NIO is as simple as changing the `protocol` attribute of the [`<Connector>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) element in `/conf/server.xml` to `"org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"`.

Comment: I have considered that, but i don't know if that would damage classes that rely on ThreadLocal, like Spring OpenSessionInViewFilter.

Comment: If those classes are well-written that it uses `ThreadLocal#remove()` the right way, then I don't forsee problems. Even more, threads for HTTP servlet requests are already by default pooled. In real world production environments, NIO is more than often standard turned on.

Comment: +1 this is a way to solve it. Not sure to the orig question on why it doesn't recover.. id say some kind of bug in how unused threads are killed off, leading to some kind of livelock or such

Comment: There is still only a single thread per request. NIO just means that you have multiple threads per HTTP connection, rather than just one.

Answer (score 0):

I think may be a bug in Tomcat and according to the issue:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48843

should be fixed in Tomcat 6.0.27 and 5.5.30